# Seqelize transaction rollback is not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize as an ORM for my MySQL database. In the following code, the rollback is not working even though it is been called.

It is supposed to rollback the value in the table 'numberseqs' but it keeps on increasing even though the catch part of the code is been executed. That is, I confirm that the rollback is been executed.

````
    async create(req, res) {
        const t = await SEQUELIZE.transaction()
        let lastGenerated = 0
        try
        {
            const numberSeqData = await numberSeq.findOne({ where: { document: 'project' } }, { transaction: t})
            if (numberSeqData)
            {
                lastGenerated = numberSeqData.lastGenerated + 1
                await numberSeq.update({ lastGenerated }, { where: { document: 'project' }},
                { transaction: t}
                )
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Error('NumberSeq not found')
            }
            const projectNew = await project.create({ 
                ProjectNumber : `PRJ-${lastGenerated}`,
                Name: req.body.name,
                Stage: req.body.stage,
                StartDate: req.body.startDate,
                EndDate: req.body.endDate,
                Description: req.body.description,
                IsActive: req.body.isActive,
            },{ transaction: t})
            await t.commit()
            res.status(200).send(projectNew)
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            await t.rollback()
            res.status(400).send(err)
        }
    }```


I tried setting up the transaction isolation level, but it didn't helped.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated the transaction `t` in the wrong place in both `findOne` and `update`. the `transaction` option should be right next to `where` option:

```js
const numberSeqData = await numberSeq.findOne({
  where: { document: 'project' },
  transaction: t
})
if (numberSeqData)
{
  lastGenerated = numberSeqData.lastGenerated + 1
  await numberSeq.update({ lastGenerated }, {
    where: { document: 'project' },
    transaction: t
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you, for the help. The code changes which you have mentioned, has worked.